# Can't figure this code out. Please give back some insight

Tags: java, methods

```
// This application displays some math facts
public class DebugThree2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      add();
      subtract();
      System.out.println("Java");
      int a = 2, b = 5, c = 10;
      add("a" + "b");
      add("b" + "c");
      subtract("c" - "a");            
    }

    public static void add() {
      System.out.println("The sum of " + "a" + "and" + "b" + "is" + "a" + "b");
    }

    public static void subtract() {
      System.out.println("The difference between " + "a" + "and" + "b" + "is" + "a" - "b");
    }
}
```

I keep getting the errors `method add in class DebugThree2 cannot be applied to given types`, `bad operand types for binary operator '-'`

Comment: Why do you put your variables between `"`? Why your methods don't receive any argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  add();
  subtract();
  System.out.println("Java");
  int a = 2, b = 5, c = 10;
  add(a,b);
  add(b,c);
  subtract(c,a);            
}
public static void add(int a, int b)
{
  System.out.println("The sum of " + a +
     " and " +  b  + " is " + (a+b));
}
public static void subtract(int a, int b)
{
  System.out.println("The difference between " +
    a + " and  " + b + " is " + (a-b));
}
```

I think something like that may be more what you are looking for.  You are trying to subtract (string)b from (string)a.

```
"a" - "b"
```

You must use their actual value, by not including quotation marks.